# Outlook 365 / Exchange retention policy

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, exchange-2013

Several weeks ago I assigned the following retention policy to one of my shared account with an alias name *inbox*:

[image]

Today, using Powershell, I checked if the retention policy is set properly:

```
Get-Mailbox inbox | FL RetentionPolicy
```

> `14 Day Delete w/ No Recovery`

Then I manually run the retention policy as follows:

```
Start-ManagedFolderAssistant inbox
```

---

As mentioned earlier, this retention policy was set weeks ago and after running the command above, I expected to see the policy being in effect within an hour or so. However, I still see all old messages being kept in all folders, including *Deleted Items* folder, although for that particular folder I set a retention tag that permanently remove all messages after 1 day.

Is there any way to check some journal log to see when (timestamp) had the retention policy run and applied for a particular account, and/or to see some details why such messages were not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Given this situation, it is suggested to confirm whether you have enabled the Retention hold feature for this Shared mailbox. Because Retention hold suspends the processing of a retention policy for a mailbox.

[Retention Policy not applying to shared mailbox](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/retention-policy-not-applying-to-shared-mailbox/b3579531-d6e9-4d28-aa99-b36c2e71ed57)

Comment: There was/is not hold. The `RetentionHoldEnabled` returns `false`